# Android Sqlite and notifyChanged()

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

Can anyone help me in populating the values from database and show in listview using the `notifychanged()`

Comment: I am able to fetch the values from sqlite but without refreshing the activity I want to update the listview

Comment: Do you want to use recycler view??? if you are able to fetch data you can easily populate right.. What is the issue ??

Comment: Can you please have a better title and more detailed information in the content with your effort?

Answer (score 0):

you do not need to refresh activity. after fetching data from database you update your `ArrayList` or something like that, and call `notifiyDataSetChanged()` and it is done.

Comment: ya #karimkhan i am using ArrayList only but my problem is I am inserting the data from different source so if I want to see the updated data I want to again reload the Activity that makes my scroll potion change so please help me

Comment: just update your datalist and call notifydatasetchanged()